# Weightless model in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, physics-engine

I'm trying to create a circumference or a translucent cylinder that floats mid-air in this world: https://github.com/space-ros/demos/blob/main/mars_rover/worlds/mars_curiosity.world

I want to draw a circumference around the rover indicating a distance within which it should stay.

I've tried adding a new model to the world with only `visual` and no `collisions`, but it still falls to (and through) the ground. I've tried using `<gravity>0</gravity>` inside the model's `link` tag, as well as `<turnGravityOff>true</turnGravityOff>` and `<turnGravityOff>1</turnGravityOff>`.

I also tried setting `<intertial><mass value="0" /></intertial>`.

Does anyone know how this can be done?